# DBT source freshness result alert/ database store option

Tags: dbt

I want to store output of "dbt source freshness" command result in database or send email of freshness test for warning and error records only.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use this package to store audit logs in your db: [`dbt-event-logging`](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-event-logging)

**Add to your dbt project yml:**

```
# dbt_project.yml
...

models:
  ...
  pre-hook: "{{ logging.log_model_start_event() }}"
  post-hook: "{{ logging.log_model_end_event() }}"
```

I imagine you can alter the `sources:` attribute in a similar way – though I am not 100% sure...

Alternatively, you can create your own `post-hook` event – usage becomes complex really quickly: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/pre-hook-post-hook

Comment: Thanks Yaakov, when I am trying to install package getting error    Package dbt-labs/dbt-event-logging was not found in the package index Code: 10006

Comment: Not sure why you're getting that error. Is your package listed in your project? https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/package-management#hub-packages-recommended